# Heterogeneous container of base class when the derived instances are not pointers

Tags: c++

I have a base class and I want to store instances of its derivatives in a collection of some sort.

At first I created a map:

```
 std::map<int, Variable> varriableItems;
```

and then ussing templates I created functions for each derivative and I tried passing in the derivatives like so:

```
template <>
void Array::addToMap<Number>(Number input)
{
numberVariables[itemCount_] = input;    
itemCount_++;
}
```

By doing so this function was not called because everything was of type Variable of course and I found out about [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

So instead I changed my map to take in pointers to my base class

```
  std::map<int, Variable*> varriableItems;
```

but the problem I have is that all my objects are not created as pointers so I could not pass them in and I was getting errors.
*No suitable conversion from "Number" to "Variable*" exists.

Due to my implementation I can only create instances of objects 
like so:

```
auto aNumberVariable = Number{50};
```

Ofcourse if I instead do:

```
Number aNumberVariable = new Number(50);
```

it works great.

The reason am doing this is explained bellow.

Please bear with me because this is a weird assignment.

We were asked to create a program that behaves/understands the syntax of a programming language called Logo, without actually analyzing the text as an input file, but rather "disguise" it to appear as such while in fact we just use C++ using what we learned from C++ and lots of overloads and pre-processor tricks

We have to be able to make our own "types" of variables called **NUMBER**,**WORD**,**BOOLEAN**,**ARRAY**, **LIST**,**SENTENCE**.

To declare them we have to use(note no semi-colons should be used):

```
//define number variable with value 21
MAKE number = NUMBER: 21
//define hello variable with value “hello”
MAKE hello = WORD: “hello”
//define myMoves variable contains list of turtle moves
MAKE myMoves = LIST [
    LIST [WORD: “FORWARD”, NUMBER: 100],
    LIST [WORD: “LEFT”, NUMBER: 90],
    LIST [WORD: “FORWARD”, NUMBER: 100]
]
//define array variable with empty array
MAKE array = ARRAY {
    number,
    hello,
    NUMBER: 12
    BOOLEAN: TRUE,
    ARRAY {
        myMoves,
        LIST [WORD: “BACK”, NUMBER: 100]
    }
}
//define book variable with sentence type
MAKE book = SENTENCE (hello, WORD: “hello!”)
```

That's just a small part, we later have to support functions, nested loops , etc.
So do this I have to find a way to use the colon since I cannot overload it, so I did this:

```
//Create an instance of Number and write the first half of the ternary operator so we 
//always get the false value so we can use the : like this
#define NUMBER  Number{} = (false) ? 0 
//semicolon infront for the previous command that needs it
#define MAKE ;auto
```

So now this:

```
//following commands will deal with the semicolon
MAKE myNumber = NUMBER: 21
```

worked great and it actually gets replaced by the processor to this:

```
auto myNumber = Number{} = (false) ? 0 : 21
```

So i worked with this for all my derivatives and I proceeded to overload operators to compare them, implement if else function in a similarly weird syntax.

Now I either have to figure out a way to make this work again but this time creating them as pointer instead (Which I assume is the only way for this to work, but I so far I couldn't figure it out) or create a single class for all types but doing it in separate objects that all inherit from a single base class makes more sense to me.

And am not sure how strict they will be, it is an unconventional project assignment for sure.

The reason I want to hold them together in a container is so I can then implement an Array and list object that can hold every type. At first I tried to use a different container for each type and made an iterator to iterate multiple maps separately, but when I got to the LIST implementation things got weird.

The list syntax is using the brackets [ ] which can only get 1 input value, so the idea was to collect them by overloading the comma operator and pass in one value to the list object.

I know this is weird , thank you for your time

Comment: What you described is [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which requires a modern compiler with C++17 support.

Comment: Oh god, here is that crazy Logo DSEL again :D

Comment: I'm very curious in what world this is a useful assignment to give people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't read through all of your post. (actually I did because your task is so ... beyond words) but if you need polymorphism in a container and you also need the container to hold the objects, then the solution is `unique_ptr`:

```
container<std::unique_ptr<Base>>
```

In your case it would go something along this:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<Variable>> varriableItems;

varriableItems[0] = std::make_unique<Number>(50);
```

Comment: This worked! I looked it up a bit and I just used shared_ptr , seemed a better fit for my needs. Thank you so much, have a great day.